# Have dashes rather than underscores in URL's in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'd really like to be able to use Laravel (3) and have dashes as url separators rather than underscores.

I'd like to be able to do this automatically rather than having to define a new route for every_single_page too.

I can't see how to achieve this, and make sure that Laravel works as normal at the same time.

Any help would be really gratefully received!

Answer (score 4):

Just use :

```
return Str::slug('My First Blog Post!');
```

It will echo a link like ***mypage/my-first-blog-post***

You can also be more precise :

```
return Str::slug('My First Blog Post!', '_');
```

Will give ***mypage/my_first_blog_post***

Answer (score 2):

I've created [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/1965) to the 3.x branch that fixes this issue.

You can use both [patch](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/1965.patch) or [my still-supported fork](https://github.com/neoascetic/laravel) of 3.x branch of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing the - by _ with a .htaccess file.

Comment: But, if i create a url in my app of site.com/i-am-great will that go to the i_am_great method in my default controller method if i use a .htaccess?

Comment: You need to figger out what RewriteRule you need to use, but I think it is possible with .htaccess

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a go at the very least rather than theorise on here :)

Comment: Ok, post your answer if it works so you can help anyone in the feature.

Comment: Ok, i have tried this with a .htaccess rule but that doesn't work. Thinking about it, i don't think this will work at all using .htaccess, i think it needs to be done at Laravels routing level. I was using this    RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
    RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]